# LaTeX Flow Graph: Determine node and circle size dependent on text length?

Tags: tikz-styles, graphs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{warwickthesis}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type

\usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=4pt,auto,node distance=8cm,minimum size=1cm,thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {Employment};

  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {Unemployment};

  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=1] {Inactivity};


  \path

    (1) edge [bend right] node {400(t)} (2)
            edge [bend left] node {500} (3)

    (2) edge node [below]{100} (1)
            edge [bend left] node {300} (3)

    (3) edge node[right] {500} (1)
        edge node[below] {200} (2);     

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Can you show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) what you did so far? That would give is something to start with.

Comment: Nodes automatically adjust to the size of their content in Ti*k*Z, so you must be doing something strange or not using nodes. So either stop doing the something strange or start using nodes.

Comment: I just started using LaTex. Excue me but I am not that familiar with it and I am very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't know tikz very well, but I get an error  `Unknown arrow tip kind 'stealth''`. Perhaps this example should be edited to remove the single quote mark (after stealth) from the example.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code but note that an MWE should be a complete minimal document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Otherwise people have to guess what packages and things they need to make your example work in the same wrong way that it is working for you!

Comment: Your circles already get larger if you put more in them. What are you trying to do that's not working and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So I edited everything above. I just want three simile circles and arrows from and out of those circles as shown above. But when I write something inside them they get bigger. I want everything in the same size...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{warwickthesis}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
%\usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type
%\usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=4pt,
    auto,
    node distance=8cm,
    thick,
main node/.style = {circle, draw, text width=2cm, align=center,
                    font=\bfseries}
                        ]

  \node[main node] (1) {Employ\-ment};
  \node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {Unemploy\-ment};
  \node[main node] (3) [below right of=1] {Inactivity};

\path (1)   edge [bend right]   node {400(t)} (2)
            edge [bend left]    node {500} (3)
      (2)   edge                node [swap] {100} (1)
            edge [bend left]    node {300} (3)
      (3)   edge                node[swap] {500} (1)
            edge                node[swap] {200} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly! So I need to use `text width`. I understand. Thanks a lot! I will keep trying.

Comment: Instead "thank you" this site use system for  voting of the good answer (by clicking on pen at top left side of answer/question, I just up-vote your question; see your reputation) and accept the one, which is the best/useful for you :-)